# Postman - How to run tests during 'Proxy Debug Session'?

Tags: postman

I'm trying to extract specific data from multiple responses and I thought that using the 'Tests' mechanism would be best for me.

The requests are dynamically changing and I need to use the 'Proxy debug session' in order to get those responses.

Is there a way to run tests during a 'Proxy debug session'?

Note: I even tried to save the pairs of (request, response) from the 'proxy debug session' and extract data from multiple responses but couldn't find a way to do it neither because those pairs are saved as 'examples', and the 'Runner' won't run Tests on 'examples'.